# Retrieving data from SQL Server using LINQ

Tags: sql, wcf, linq

How can I retrieve data from a SQL Server using LINQ and display each tuple in a table in the UI? 
I would also like to know how I can convert the data retrieved in to JSON and send it to clients who accessed that particular service.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: There are dozens (probably hundreds) of tutorials explaining how to do everything you've asked for. Have you tried Google?

Comment: A great place to start is http://www.asp.net/get-started

Comment: I am using a WCF service, not ASP.NET. And yep, I have tried googling it but haven't found what i'm looking for so far.

Comment: If you haven't found answers on Google, then asking a 2-scentence question that is a broad as "Give me all the code to query the DB, turn the result into JSON, sent it over WCF, get the result, and display it in ASP.NET" isn't going to help either. You are basically asking for someone to write you an entire tiered application and give you the code.  There are dozens if not hundreds of solutions to your "question".

Comment: @jrummell - WCF and ASP.NET are in no way related. Not sure why you would think they are... WCF can be hosted through IIS, much like ASP.NET, but it uses a different handler.

Comment: @rally25rs I wouldn't go that far. They are related in that you can [include WCF services in an ASP.NET web application project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx). But you are correct that it uses a different handler/pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How can I retrieve data from a SQL Server using LINQ?**  Add a data context (.dbml) to your project and link it to your SQL database, adding in all the tables.  You use the `MyDatabaseContext` class to interface to the database and execute LINQ queries.

**and display each tuple in a table in the UI?**  Create a GridView using a LinqDataSource with your new DataContext to pull in the appropriate data and display it.

**convert the data retrieved in to JSON..**  use something like the open-source [JSON.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) library.

**and send it to clients who accessed that particular service?**  Add a web service project to your solution (.wcf or .asmx), create an appropriate interface for the methods that should be called and implement them to return the correct data.

---

Note that at this phase in the project, you should be doing something called *research*, not asking questions.  Google is a place to start.  Come back when you have specific questions or implementation issues in trying to build your solution.  What you've given us is a *spec*, not a question, and those do not belong here.